# Add value in char array last index using C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, hex

I want to send array through `socket`.The length of array is 16 where last four bytes is value.
To make this dynamic I am trying to add value to the end of array.

I have `unsigned char` array

Eg:

```
unsigned char command[] = { 0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0x11, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x24 };
```

I want to add value at the end of this array.

```
int value = 380;
```

So hex representation of 380 is 17c

Now the array becomes

```
0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0x11, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x7c
```

where last four byte is value.

I have try to add last four byte by first creating array which have values

```
char* temp = "00000380"
```

and then using `for loop` add this to new array

**Code**

```
int m_imageX = 380;

char m_buf[3] = { '\0' };
int count = 0;
int value = 0;
int m_index;

unsigned char command[16];
unsigned char commandss[] = { 0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0x11, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x24 };
for (m_index = 0; m_index < 12; m_index++)
{
    command[m_index] = commandss[m_index];
}

std::string m_tmp = std::to_string(m_imageX);
char const *tmp = m_tmp.c_str();
char comm[8];
int size = strlen(tmp);
for (int i = 0; i < 8 - size; i++)
{
    comm[i] = '0';
}
for (int i = 8 - size; i < 8; i++)
{
    comm[i] = tmp[count++];
}

count = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{

    if (j > 0  && j % 2 == 0)
    {
        command[m_index++] = atoi(m_buf);
        count = 0;
        memset(m_buf, NULL, sizeof(m_buf));
        m_buf[count++] = comm[j];
    }
    else
    {
        m_buf[count++] = comm[j];
    }
}

command[m_index] = atoi(m_buf);
```

But when I sending this I found on wireshark that the array transmitted has value like

```
    0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0x11, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x50
```

So can anyone tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use shift and bitwise operators to break the integer in to bytes, and store in `std::vector`

`0x17c & 0xFF` results `0x7c`. Right shift by 8 bits and repeat to get the next byte. The example below will add the bytes in big-endian format `00 00 01 7C`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> vec =
    { 0x40, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x08, 0x11, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0xa1, 0x24 };

    int num = 380;
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        bytes.insert(bytes.begin(), num & 0xFF);
        num = num >> 8;
    }

    for(auto e : bytes)
        vec.push_back(e);

    for(auto e : vec)
        std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> 40 1 0 2 0 8 11 4c 0 0 a1 24 0 0 1 7c
> ```

Comment: I have to send that through socket for that I have to convert that in unsigned char array?

Comment: `vec.data()` gives access to bytes as `unsigned char`. For copying, use `unsigned char command[16]={0}; memcpy(command, vec.data(), vec.size());` but it's not needed.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned above I  command the value is represented in 4 bytes

Comment: Change the loop to copy 4 bytes as shown in edit. This will copy bytes in big-endian form, I am not sure what your goal is here.

Answer (score 2):

You are considering that characters representing your strings have the same binary representation as your original number. It's not the case.

You may want to use a reinterpret_cast to be able to transfer the binary representation of your size in the char array:

```
int64_t m_imageX = 380;
const char* tmp = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&m_imageX);

for (int i = 8 - size; i < 8; i++)
{
    comm[i] = tmp[count++];
}
```

Comment: then how will I add this array to another?

Comment: Just as before, although you don't even need `comm`, you can just add it to your commands.